# CgMiner past version 3.4 cannot see USB Block Eurptors (Windows)

Tags: windows, cgminer, asic

I've been using [CgMiner 3.4.1](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/3.4/) since late September. It can see my four USB Block Erupters, and works:

```
 cgminer version 3.4.1 - Started: [2013-11-20 07:48:07]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (5s):1.223G (avg):978.4Mh/s | A:18  R:0  HW:1  WU:17.4/m
 ST: 2  SS: 0  NB: 1  LW: 37  GF: 0  RF: 0
 Connected to stratum.bitcoin.cz diff 3 with stratum as user joesmith
 Block: 00070bedfe64cbc8...  Diff:609M  Started: [07:48:07]  Best share: 124
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [P]ool management [S]ettings [D]isplay options [Q]uit
 AMU 0:                | 307.2M/327.5Mh/s | A:12 R:0 HW:0 WU:10.0/m
 AMU 1:                | 267.8M/314.6Mh/s | A: 0 R:0 HW:0 WU: 2.5/m
 AMU 2:                | 280.3M/322.7Mh/s | A: 6 R:0 HW:0 WU: 3.7/m
 AMU 3:                | 127.4M/308.9Mh/s | A: 3 R:0 HW:1 WU:10.5/m
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 [2013-11-20 07:48:43] Accepted 1326b92d Diff 13/3 AMU 0
 [2013-11-20 07:48:47] Accepted 3e086003 Diff 4/3 AMU 0
 [2013-11-20 07:48:58] Accepted 487047eb Diff 3/3 AMU 3
```

But it [regularly crashes](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=28402.10980) [with a](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=28402.10960) [stack overflow](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=28402.12395;wap).

About a month ago i tried to upgrade to [CgMiner 3.6](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/3.6/), but it fails to find my USB devices:

```
 cgminer version 3.6.0 - Started: [2013-11-20 07:49:52]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (5s):0.000 (avg):0.000h/s | A:0  R:0  HW:0  WU:0.0/m
 ST: 2  SS: 0  NB: 1  LW: 2  GF: 0  RF: 0
 Connected to stratum.bitcoin.cz diff 3 with stratum as user joesmith
 Block: 00070bedfe64cbc8...  Diff:609M  Started: [07:49:52]  Best share: 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [P]ool management [S]ettings [D]isplay options [Q]uit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 [2013-11-20 07:49:49] Started cgminer 3.6.0
 [2013-11-20 07:49:49] Loaded configuration file cgminer.conf
 [2013-11-20 07:49:51] No devices detected!
 [2013-11-20 07:49:51] Waiting for USB hotplug devices or press q to quit
 [2013-11-20 07:49:51] Probing for an alive pool
 [2013-11-20 07:49:52] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 3
 [2013-11-20 07:49:52] Network diff set to 609M
```

So i reverted to `3.4.1`, living with the semi-daily crashes and having to remember to restart CgMiner. This morning i tested [CgMiner 3.8](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/3.8/), hoping they fixed its inability to see USB Block Eruptors (and the stack overflow). Unfortunately it *still* does not see USB devices:

```
 cgminer version 3.8.0 - Started: [2013-11-20 07:44:46]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (5s):0.000 (avg):0.000h/s | A:0  R:0  HW:0  WU:0.0/m
 ST: 2  SS: 0  NB: 1  LW: 16  GF: 0  RF: 0
 Connected to stratum.bitcoin.cz diff 1 with stratum as user joesmith
 Block: 70bedfe6...  Diff:609M  Started: [07:44:46]  Best share: 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [P]ool management [S]ettings [D]isplay options [Q]uit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 [2013-11-20 07:44:42] Started cgminer 3.8.0
 [2013-11-20 07:44:42] Loaded configuration file cgminer.conf
 [2013-11-20 07:44:44] AMU 0 SendWork usb write err:(-7) LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
 [2013-11-20 07:44:44] FAIL: USB get_lock not found (3:2)
 [2013-11-20 07:44:44] FAIL: USB remove not already in use (3:2)
 [2013-11-20 07:44:45] No devices detected!
 [2013-11-20 07:44:45] Waiting for USB hotplug devices or press q to quit
 [2013-11-20 07:44:45] Probing for an alive pool
 [2013-11-20 07:44:46] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 3
 [2013-11-20 07:44:46] Network diff set to 609M
 [2013-11-20 07:45:14] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 1
 [2013-11-20 07:45:14] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2013-11-20 07:45:14] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
```

So i am, once again, reverted to CgMiner 3.4.1.

What did they break after CgMiner 3.4, and how do i fix it?

## WinUSB

Just to preempt people who might suggest it, rather than offering any insight, i re-ran [zadiag](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) [2.0.1.162](http://zadig.akeo.ie/downloads/zadig_v2.0.1.162.exe) (Updated 11/20/2013), and *"reinstalled"* the **WinUSB** driver for my for USB devices (and rebooted)

[image]

No effect.

What is CgMiner 2.8 doing wrong that CgMiner 2.4 did right?

**Edit**: Using Silicon Labs own VCP (Virtual COM Port driver):

[image]

gives the error (in BfgMiner):

```
usb_devinfo_scan: Error opening device: LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

In CgMiner it gives:

```
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 1:3
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 3:3
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 3:2
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 3:6
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 3:8
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 3:10
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 3:11
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 3:12
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 3:13
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 6:2
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 8:3
USB init, open device failed, err -12, you need to install a WinUSB driver for - AMU device 8:1
```

So i've changed it trying every driver with some of the miners. Three are using the **libusb-win32** driver, three are using the **libusbx.org** driver, and the rest are using the **Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge** driver:

[image]

Both **CgMiner** and **BfgMiner** detect no devices.

Answer (score 2):

cgminer's FPGA and ASIC support was originally taken from [BFGMiner](http://bfgminer.com). Due to the maintainers of GPU mining being upset over the obsoletion of GPU mining, they forked the project and eventually (poorly) rewrote the FPGA/ASIC drivers. You are seeing the effects of that.

BFGMiner continues to maintain the original (working) drivers, but you will need to remove the Zadig/WinUSB driver and install [the official CP210x driver](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/pages/usbtouartbridgevcpdrivers.aspx) provided by Silabs. (CP210x is the chip used by the Block Erupters)

Comment: BfgMiner seems to require the `libusb` driver. On launch it gives the error `usb_devinfo_scan: Error opening device: LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`

Comment: Only for devices that speak raw USB, not block erupters.

Answer (score -1):

4.10.0 found my old asic usb miner